# Issue on Creating Checkbox Field On Custom Post type

Tags: custom-field, metabox

Can you please look at this demo let me know how I can create and save a checkbox as a custom field in Custom Post Type?

```
function render_metas( $post )
{
    $we_productMetas = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $onSale = isset( $we_productMetas['onSale_box'] ) ? esc_attr( $we_productMetas['onSale_box'][0] ) : '';
?>

<input type="checkbox" class=""  name="onSale_box" id="onSale-box" value="<?php echo $onSale; ?>" />


<?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'we_metas_save' );
function we_metas_save( $post_id )
{
if( isset( $_POST['onSale_box'] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'onSale_box', wp_kses( $_POST['onSale_box'], $allowed ) );
    }

}
```

Comment: And how do you call `render_metas` function? Is it bound to some hook?

Comment: You can use **ACF** for custom fields.